# Custom JsonConverter gets reader with TokenType "EndObject" when it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I have a stream with an array of JSON objects which come in two different formats but contain the same sort of data, and I want to deserialize both of these formats into the same type so my view doesn't need custom logic for both formats of data. Currently I am handling this using a custom JsonConverter.

Here is my model:

```
[JsonObject]
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyCommonObjectJsonConverter))]
public class MyCommonObject {
    // some common fields, e.g.
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my custom JsonConverter:

```
public class MyCommonObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // don't need to worry about serialization in this case, only
        // reading data
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        MyCustomObject result;
        if (IsFormatOne(jObject))
        {
            // the structure of the object matches the first format,
            // so just deserialize it directly using the serializer
            result = serializer.Deserialize<MyCustomObject>(reader);
        }
        else if (IsFormatTwo(jObject))
        {
            result = new MyCustomObject();

            // initialize values from the JObject
            // ... 
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown format, cannot deserialize");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(MyCustomObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    // Definitions of IsFormatOne and IsFormatTwo
    // ...
}
```

However, when I deserialize the first format's objects, I get an error saying that it can't load the JObject, since the JsonReader has TokenType "EndToken". I'm not sure why this is happening, the data I am loading in is correctly formatted. Any suggestions on what I should be looking out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to fall back to the default deserialization when reading your `MyCommonObject`, however:

- The call to `JObject.Load(reader)` has already advanced the reader past the object, as you have observed, and
- calling `serializer.Deserialize<MyCustomObject>(reader)` would in any event result in infinite recursion.

The customary way to avoid unwanted recursion in `ReadJson()` in cases like this is to allocate your result manually then call [`serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), result)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm).  I.e.:

```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        MyCommonObject result;
        if (IsFormatOne(jObject))
        {
            result = (existingValue as MyCommonObject ?? (MyCommonObject)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator()); // Reuse existingValue if present
            // the structure of the object matches the first format,
            // so just deserialize it directly using the serializer
            using (var subReader = jObject.CreateReader())
                serializer.Populate(subReader, result);
        }
        else if (IsFormatTwo(jObject))
        {
            result = (existingValue as MyCommonObject ?? (MyCommonObject)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());

            // initialize values from the JObject
            // ... 
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown format, cannot deserialize");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out while writing this up, calling `serializer.Deserialize<MyCustomObject>(reader)` was recursing into my converter again, at which point the reader will have reached an end token from being loaded into the JObject, making the TokenType equal to EndToken. I should have checked the stack trace more carefully. For now I'm going to write custom initialization logic for both formats, making my model class format-agnostic.

Comment: As a follow-up, is there any way to convert a JSON object into a model without using the model's custom converter? i.e. just using the default one

Comment: The customary way to avoid recursion in `ReadJson()` when you want to fall back on the standard behavior is to allocate the object yourself then call [`serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), result)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm).